# mongoose filter collection based on another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Author collection

```json
[
   {
      "_id":"asdasd2dqdfwefwe",
      "books":[
         "ISBN2e242",
         "ISBNasdasdasd"
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"asdasd2dqdfwefwe",
      "books":[
         "ISBN2e242",
         "ISBN1111sdasd"
      ]
   }
]
```

Q1. How I can get flat array of all **unique** ISBN using mongoose query?
Should return `['ISBN2e242','ISBNasdasdasd','ISBN1111sdasd']`

If there's another collection books,

```json
[
   {"ISBN":"ISBN2e242", "title":"some book1"},
   {"ISBN":"ISBN2e299", "title":"some book2"},
   {"ISBN":"ISBN1111sdasd", "title":"some book3"},
   {"ISBN":"ISBN2e242", "title":"some book4"},
   {"ISBN":"ISBNasdasdasd", "title":"some book5"}, 
]
```

Q2. How can I get only those books for which ISBN resulted in Q1.? Can these two operations be merged in 1 query or aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:**

Use `$unwind` to deconstruct the array `books` and `$group` using `$addToSet` to avoid repeated values.

```
yourAuthorCollection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$books"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "books": {
        "$addToSet": "$books"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KbCbz5nhNE1)

**Second question:**

Add a `$lookup` stage like this:

```
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "books",
    "localField": "books",
    "foreignField": "ISBN",
    "as": "books"
  }
}
```

As the last `books` output was an array with all ISBNs you can join the collection with `books`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/00AsjLgw00x)

Comment: neat and comprehensive. thanks